ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from partially initialized module 'keras'
i am building a number plate detection system. i am using tensorflow 2.5 and i am getting this error
ImportError: cannot import name 'version' from partially initialized module 'keras' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\mails\anaconda3\envs\tfod\lib\site-packages\keras_init_.py)

Please add sample code for which you are getting this error. It helps debug the issue.
Also follow formatting guide for posting questions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I had the same error, but in my case the error was for weaviate. I uninstalled the module with:
pip uninstall weaviate weaviate-client 

And then reinstalled it with:
pip install weaviate weaviate-client

and it worked for me. I do not know if we both had the error for the same reason, but you can give it a try.
